# Trying to write csv file to R variable

Tags: r, csv, export-to-csv

My intention is to format a simple matrix in csv format. As I need to further process the formatted lines, I don't want to write the formatted string to a file.

I already tried using `textConnection`, which seems to be the right approach.

```
m<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2)
result<-write.csv(m, file=textConnection(csvData), row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

I'm expecting `csvData` to contain the contents of the formatted csv (file) as a vector containing the lines.

I get the error:

```
Error in textConnection(csvData) : invalid 'text' argument
```

What is the proper usage of `textConnection`?

**Revised question**

After some trying and cleaning all variables I ended up with

```
rm(list = ls())
m<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2)
result<-write.csv(m, file=textConnection("csvData", "w"), row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

This produces at least no errors, but I ended with a warning that `col.names` are ignored. The content of `csvData` is also not what I expected

```
> csvData
[1] "\"V1\",\"V2\"" "1,3"           "2,4"
```

How to remove the header?

**My solution**

After trying I found, that `write.csv` should be replaced by `write.table`.

```
rm(list = ls())
m<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow=2)
result<-write.table(m, file=textConnection("csvData", "w"), row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE, sep=";")
```

Comment: Does `write.csv(m, "mymatrix.csv")` generate the desired output? Check it via `read.csv("mymatrix.csv")`.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the header and row names in the output file. I thought `write.csv(m, "mymatrix.csv", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)` should do it, right?

Comment: But `col.names` is ignored, so why `write.csv` has a paramater `col.names`, which is just ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `write.csv()` from `MASS`

```
MASS::write.matrix(m, file = textConnection("csvData", "w"), sep = ";")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to write to a file. I wanted to write to vector containing the lines of the file. I already found a solution. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Hilarious. Many thanks, even though I already found a working solution for myself.